# How to normalize and load pandas DataFrame into Django backend

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

I have found a lot of code samples looking to load a pandas DataFrame into a Django backend as a whole table ( not breaking up the table and normalizing the data into separate tables with foreign key relationships ).  I am not sure that this is the most efficient way to store pandas DataFrame tables in a db.  I believe it should be broken down into separate tables and connected via a ForeignKey.

Is there any python library that will do this for you ?  What would be a good approach to achieve this ?

Comment: You will almost certainly need to normalise the data yourself

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  and then the models would be created around the normalization, correct ?  This was my original thought, but wasn't sure given that I haven't seen it implemented like this online.